# As we can use ActionScript in Adobe Flash, is it possible to use any coding for such action in Adobe After Effect?

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript, adobe, after-effects

As we can use **ActionScript** in **Adobe Flash**(**for Mouse Hide and Automatic FULLSCREEN, etc.**), than we publish as **.SWF or .EXE**, is it possible to use any coding for such action in **Adobe After Effect**?

Comment: Sorry sir, Pls i could not understand .....

Comment: hm, ok, i m using Flash for TV Ads and other media Ads. So i use some script (AS2 or AS3) in my Flash project. I like to know sir, is it possible to use such CODE in After Effect to achieve the actions like FULLScreen and  Mouse Hide, etc.....

Comment: After Effects is primarily used as a software for video editors, to create motion graphics and also visual effects. So, no.

Comment: Thank u sir for good information.